# Creating a bool array and setting value to true or false based on times

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-core, boolean

I am fairly new to programming.

I am trying to create a bool array based on 30 minute intervals within a day, therefore the size of the array will be 48 (24 hours * 2(30 min intervals)). All the values will be false to begin with, but based on Start Time and End Time, I want to set values to true.

For example,

StartTime : `02:00:00`
EndTime: `04:00:00`

I want the boolean array to look like:

```
F, F, F, F, T, T, T, T, F, F ...
```

Comment: What have you tried? You have to actually try something to get some help here. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Create a loop and increment your time each time, T or F will be basedon if the time is within start end.  If you show what you have tried, we can help please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Have a look at the `BitArray` class.  You can declare one like this:  `var b = new BitArray(48);`,  Then set values like this:  `b[3] = true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to create the array you described.

```
public bool[] timeCheck(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    bool[] output = new bool[48];
    int startIndex = ((start.Hour * 60) + start.Minute)/30;
    int endIndex = ((end.Hour * 60) + end.Minute)/30;
    for (int i = startIndex ;i <= endIndex; i++)
         output[i] = true;
    return output;
}
```

In this code we define the start and end indices allowing us to only spend time on the values we need to set to `true`, all other values are left as the default value of `false`

The reason we can do this confidently is because we are using the `DateTime` and `int` type so we know that the `startIndex` and `endIndex` must exist within our array. the maximum value for `(start.Hour * 60) + start.Minute)` is 1,439‬ min. When this is divided by 30 we get 47 the last index of our array.

If start time comes after end time, we simply have no true values as the for loop ends immediately.

This code does not take into account difference in the date, it only accounts for time. So if your start is 10pm on Wednesday and your end 2am on Thursday no values are true. I will leave that one up to you to solve.